# Android, SQL Database Failure 1 syntax error? Can't find what catlog is talking about

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

> Database - Failure 1 (near "text" : syntax error) on 0x25c768 when preparing...

This is the error that shows up in LogCat when I try to run my app. I have the following code setting up the database:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "recipesDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "recipes";
private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
public static final String KEY_INGREDIENTS = "ingredients";
public static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
public static final String KEY_BOIL = "boil";
public static final String KEY_PRIMARY = "primary";
public static final String KEY_SECONDARY = "secondary";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper; // DatabaseHelper is an inner class extending SQLiteOpenHelper

private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_INGREDIENTS + " text not null, "
    + KEY_NOTES + " text not null, "
    + KEY_BOIL + " text not null, "
    + KEY_PRIMARY + " text not null, "
    + KEY_SECONDARY + " text not null); ";

private final Context cntx;

public recipesDB(Context cnt){
    this.cntx = cnt;
}
```

I'm pretty lost as to why I am getting this error since the code and syntax seem to be fine. I get a run-time error when I run the app on my phone and click on the button which opens up the activityList. There is more code not shown that opens up and catches a `SQLExpection` on `open()`, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try renaming the column "primary" -- it's a reserved word (as in primary key autoincrement...) and may be causing SQLite to choke.

Comment: That was it thanks! One more question though, as you can see from the code above I forgot to add the KEY_NAME and KEY_TYPE to the database script. Now when I run the app on my phone I get a "No such column : name" error in the DDVM. Is this because the database has already been built and coloumns can no longer be added?

Comment: You can add columns, but you need to do so explicitly with the ALTER TABLE... command.  You can do that in your helper class by incrementing your database version and putting the ALTER TABLE in the onUpgrade... method.

Comment: @Eric You can also clear the application data so it will rebuild the database from scratch. Be careful though: this clears ALL application data. The `ALTER TABLE` approach might work better.